# React Native - Handle onPress event to show image while specific ListView Pressed using Timeline ListView

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a problem to handling onpress in [Timeline Listview](https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview)

I've a code like this :

```
class Medicine extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.onEventPress = this.onEventPress.bind(this)
    this.renderSelected = this.renderSelected.bind(this)
    this.renderDetail = this.renderDetail.bind(this)
    this.state = {selected: '', visible:false}
  }

  onEventPress(data){
    this.setState({selected: data, visible:true})
  }

  renderSelected(){
    console.log(this.state.selected.url)
    if(this.state.selected){
      return <ImageViewer imageUrls={this.state.selected.url}/>
    } else{
      console.log('asdasd')
    }
  }

  renderImage(){
    console.log(this.state.selected)
    return <Image style={{width:DeviceWidth*0.3, height:DeviceWidth*0.3}} source={{uri: this.state.selected.url}}/>
  }

  renderDetail(rowData, sectionID, rowID){
    let title = <Text style={[global.global.SubHeaderText, {color:'green'}]}>{rowData.time}</Text>
    var desc = (
      <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Text style={[global.global.TextBold, {width:DeviceWidth*0.17}]}>Radiology </Text>
          <Text style={[global.global.Text, {flexWrap:'wrap', width:DeviceWidth*0.7}]}>{rowData.cat}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Text style={[global.global.TextBold, {width:DeviceWidth*0.17}]}>Description </Text>      
          <Text style={[global.global.Text, {flexWrap:'wrap', width:DeviceWidth*0.7}]}>{rowData.description == null ? '-' : rowData.description}</Text>      
        </View>
        {this.renderImage()}
      </View>
    )
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {title}
        {desc}
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Timeline 
          style={{flex: 1, marginTop:20}}
          showTime={false}
          separator={true}
          renderFullLine={true}
          circleColor={'green'}
          lineColor={'green'}
          data={this.data}
          onEventPress={this.onEventPress}
          renderDetail={this.renderDetail}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the result :

[image]

[image]

Everytime I Press one object of the list, the image showing on each list with the same image I've press, There's a way to avoid it and just showing the image on specific listView, I've tried using `rowID` from `renderDetail()` but I'm not good enough to solve the problem

My Goal: When I pressed first listView, the image should show on first ListView, and if I'm pressed 2nd ListView, the image on first ListView should disappear and the 2nd ListView Showing the image without another listView showing the same image as I've pressed,

there's a way to archive my goal anyone?

Comment: anyone have an idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the structure of your `data`, but my guess is that `URL` is a property of every list item.
The `renderImage` function only considering the selected object which is stored in the `state`, but it is being called from `renderDetail` function for each list item. While `renderDetail` rendering a particular list item, `renderImage` is focused only on the selected item but ignoring the current list item.

You can pass current `rowData` to `renderImage` and conditionally display the image. Consider the below snippet

```
...
renderImage(rowData) {
 if (this.state.selected.url === rowData.url) {
  return <Image 
    style={{width:DeviceWidth*0.3, height:DeviceWidth*0.3}} 
    source={{uri: rowData.url}}
  />
 }
 return null;
}
...
renderDetail(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
  ...
  var desc = (
    <View>
      ...
      {this.renderImage(rowData)}
      ...
    </View>
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
     {title}
     {desc}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: sure, your snippet looks good, and now the `onPress` can handling with ur code, thanks for the help sir,